# tensorflow.js if exist load saved model or if not exists create and save checkpoints of model every epochEnd callback

Tags: save, load, tensorflow.js, pre-trained-model

I want to load my predefined model from localstorage and if there isn't any model at there it may be created. After every epochend i want to save model for later loads.

I searched a lot of examples to save and load models. There are some examples (like API documents) but i can't find how can i check are there any applicable model at localstorage and if there isn't, create it.

NOTE: Tensorflow solutions are not adaptable to tensorflow.js (or i can't find a way)

```js
//I need to load model from localstorage. It's not needed to use a try catch block, if there is a solution to check are there any model that can be loaded as a correct model, it can be applicable.

try{

/*
try-catch block or any function to check
*/

const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('localstorage://my-model-1');

}catch(err) {

//Create new model if not exists (i don't know it is ok or not)
  const model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1}));

}

const xs = tf.tensor([1,2,3,4,5]);
const ys = tf.tensor([3,5,7,9,11]);

async function trainModel(model, inputs, labels) {
    const learningRate = 0.01;
    const opt=tf.train.sgd(learningRate);
    model.compile({ loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: opt});
    
    return await model.fit(xs, ys, {
        epochs: 500,
        callbacks:{
            onEpochEnd: async(epoch, logs) =>{
                document.getElementById("output").innerText="Epoch:" 
                            + epoch 
                            + " Loss:" 
                            + logs.loss;
                
        /*
        and then save model to the localstorage for it can load at top of this script for use later load
        */
        
            }
        }
    })
}

var training = trainModel(model, xs, ys)


training.then(function(args){
    var prediction = model.predict(tf.tensor([6]));
    document.getElementById("output").innerText=prediction;
    prediction.print();
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
  <head>
    <title>tensorflow.js sofrası</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.7.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script src="script2.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The model can be saved after each epoch with the following:

```
onEpochEnd: async(epoch, logs) =>{
  document.getElementById("output").innerText="Epoch:" 
                            + epoch 
                            + " Loss:" 
                            + logs.loss;
                
  await model.save('localstorage://model-name');
        
}
```

If the model is already saved, we can check if localStorage contains one of the following keys: `tensorflowjs_models/model-name/info`, `tensorflowjs_models/my-model-1/model_topology`, ... It will look as the following:

```
function createModel() {
  const model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1}));
  return model
}

let myModel;
if (localStorage['tensorflowjs_models/model-name/model_info']) {
 // the model exist
 myModel = await model.save('localstorage://model-name');
} else {
 myModel = createModel()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what i exactly looking for.

Comment: Do you know any way to epoches continues to train when browser minimized?

Comment: It seems that it is per browser specification to be that way